# IntelliJ - Run External Tool Command in Debug mode

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am new to using IntelliJ, so would appreciate some advise please.

I have set up an `External Tool` that invokes a script (`build-with-glassfish.bat`). This script performs a few tasks including starting a Payara Server. I can then execute the code that is built on the server (Java) via an Angular client.

**Question**
In IntelliJ, can I start the `External Tool` that runs the script in DEBUG mode? I would like to add breakpoints and examine the java code.

**More info**
The `build-with-glassfish.bat` contains the following line, that I am guessing needs to be in debug mode.

```
echo start up the server as it deploys during the build
call asadmin start-domain domain1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be debugged by setting up a Remote.

[image]